# Finding a logical equivalent to 'greater than or is null' to prevent ms-access from reformatting query

Tags: ms-access, null, permutation

I am having some trouble creating a database in Microsoft Access. I have a series of criteria in the same row of a query, many of which look like the following

```
>=[Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_min] And <=[Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_max] Or Is Null
```

If I close then reopen the database, Microsoft Access reformats the query to a logically equivalent set of permutations using multiple rows. 
The criteria go from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFNxp.png) to looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiBXP.jpg), which creates a set of criteria so large it crashes the database. Is there a logical equivalent of the code included above that I can write, which will not reformat?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with mysql? Could you explain the connection to mysql in your connection because either the tah is incorrect or something is missing in the question. We need all info to be able to help correctly.

Comment: this is likely incorrect- it was a suggested tag that i was not sure applied. I have updated the tags to omit mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with:

```
Is Null Or Between [Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_min] And [Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_max]
```

If no success, then

```
Between Nz([Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_min], [YourFieldName]) And Nz([Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_max], [YourFieldName])
```

Further, do specify both `[Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_min]` and `[Forms]![Form1]![Tensile_max]` as *parameters* to free Access from guessing the data type of these.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help, you have made my day.